# Proof of isomorphism of a field of fractions

Tags: abstract-algebra, localization

I'm stuck with the following exercise in my algebraic geometry lecture.

> Let $A$ be a domain and $I\subset A$ be a prime ideal. Let $K$ be the field of fractions of $A$. Let $A_I$ be the subring of $K$ generated by $A$ and all $1/p$ for $p\in A\setminus I$. Let $IA_I$ be the ideal of $A_I$ generated by $I$. Show that the field of fractions of $A/I$ is isomorphic to $A_I/IA_I$.

My first thought was that this has something to do with coordinate rings, but I have no idea how to approach this problem.

Can anybody give me a hint the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: I hope that this question doesn't violate any rules. It's the first time I'm asking something on a Stackexchange site.

Comment: I don't think your question violates any rules.  You clearly listed the problem, stated your initial thoughts on it, and let us know what you are looking for (e.g., you said you want a hint in the right direction).  This question gets an A+ from me.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! If in doubt, check [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/asking). I agree with @user46944. The only issue it might have is having already been asked, but I personally do not consider it annoying.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fraction field of a domain](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/778256/fraction-field-of-a-domain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R$ be an integral domain with fraction field $F$. Then a ring homomorphism $\varphi : R \to S$ extends to a homomorphism $F \to S$ if and only if $\varphi(r)$ is invertible for all $0 \neq r \in R$.

Using this criterion, try to check that the natural map $A/I \to A_I/IA_I$ induces a homomorphism $F = \operatorname{Frac}(A/I) \to A_I/IA_I$ and then check that this is an isomorphism directly.

This result is really saying that localization commutes with quotient. We can either quotient by $I$ then localize to get the fraction field, or we can localize first then quotient.

Comment: Seems like a good approach. Thanks! I will try it again with your idea an (hopefully not) come back with concrete problems.